# How to use the past continuous

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

I worked there for two months

When it comes to this sentence there is no
Reason to use the past continuous unless i want to emphasize the lenght, right?

I went to school when I was little

Is it possible to say

I was going to school when I was little to emphasize the lenght?

Comment: Only a comment because someone else might be able to describe the technical reason why, but to me "I was going to school when I was little" doesn't sound like it's emphasising the length. It sounds like the beginning of a story where you described what happened on your way to school one time.

Comment: It doesn't emphasise the length. It emphasises that the action was happening at the time you are talking about - "I was working there when [something happened]".

Answer (score 1):

It's **not about the length of time** whatever your teachers may have told you.

It's about whether the speaker is **choosing** to talk about the events as a continuing experience or a completed act. Sometimes there are objective reasons for choosing one or the other; sometimes there are not, and it is a free choice.

> I worked there for two months.

and

> I was working there for two months.

are both completely natural and idiomatic ways of talking about *exactly the same experience*. Sometimes there is a definable reason to choose one or the other (eg if the next thing the speaker talks about is something that happened during those two months, it would be natural to choose the second; if they go on to talk about what happened afterwards, it would be natural to choose the first). But sometimes there is no clear reason for the choice: it's just their emotions, or how they want the hearers to conceive of the experience.

> I was going to school when I was little.

is possible, but unlikely. I think this is mostly because *when I was little* is almost by definition a long time ago, so we are less likely to be conceiving it as a continuing experience. We might do, if we are wanting to talk about something that happened during it, but even there, I think the simple past is more likely.

> I went to school when I was little. One day, ....

There's a second reason in this particular case, and that is the ambiguity of the phrase *go(ing) to school*. It can mean "attending school", but it can also mean "making a journey to school".

This is not just in the past: to me, *I'm going to school* is much more likely to mean *I'm travelling to school (today)* than *I go to school (regularly)*.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I have one more question you state that using the past continuouś with " three months'" is fine but with " when I was young is not" not. Therefore, is there any "border" that something takes to long   that past continuous isn't right I mean for example I was working there for 30 years . Is it okay here to use the past continuous too?

Comment: No, there is no border, there is no rule, there is nothing "wrong" with using the continuous form with "when I was young". BUT, I find it harder to come up with reasons why you might want to do so, especially with "going to school" as I explained. But "I was working there thirty years ago" might indicate that the speaker was reminiscing about that time, was mentally placing themselves back at that time, and inviting the listener to be back then with them.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it's fine to say: "I was working there for thirty years when I met her" it implies that I met her during that time but when I want to just state a fact it's a lot more common to say I worked? And one more question When I state a fact and use the past continuous is it a big mistake or it's just akward ?